# Deployment using Ant tool

Tags: ant

After setup ANt in enviorment variable, i am checking ant version for testing its path is correctly set or not. It's showing version no. along with error

> "tools.jar" is unable to locate.

Do i need to fix it or not it just a warning message or error message, unable to recognized. Pls see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the JDK.  Based on the path shown above, it looks like you have just the JRE but I can't tell for sure.  Once you have the JDK installed, you need to Set the JAVA_HOME system environment variable to the JDK path.

To do this:

1. Right click on My Computer and choose Properties.
2. click on Advanced System settings
3. Click on Environmental Variables
4. Under System Variables, click on New
5. Set the Variable Name field to "JAVA_HOME" and the Variable Value field to the path to your JAVA JDK folder. (ie: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191)

After installing ANT, you will also want to create a ANT_HOME environment variable that points to the root folder for your ANT installation (ie: C:\Apache-Ant)

See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_prereq.htm

Comment: both jdk and ant is installed and setup environment variable and its working fine. and this tools.jar not found i got this is warning message. i can retrieve and deploy code. it is working fine.

Comment: I have both the JDK and the JRE installed and tools.jar is only under the JDK.  I still think your JAVA_HOME path is pointing to the JRE instead of the JDK but if it is working for you, I guess it doesn't matter :)